# Customizing Selection Handles of GEF figures

Tags: eclipse-gef, draw2d

Whenever a figure is selected in the GEF Editor, by default, we see a black,filled rectangle resize handles and a black border outlining the figure. I am implementing a feature where i am explicitly(through code) applying handles to a figure.

Following are some issues i am facing :

1) The handles are **not placed close to the figure**. They are placed leaving some space between handle and figure

2) I want to **change the color** filled from black to red

I am new to this kind of development so any examples of customizing these handles will be really use full.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The handles are created by the `SelectionHandlesEditPolicy` (this is an abstract class, the implementation is done in `ResizableEditPolicy`). This policy is added by GEF to a child figure when it is added to a parent that has a `ConstrainedLayoutEditPolicy` (i.e. `XYLayoutEditPolicy`).

What you can do is inherit from your container's edit policy (i.e. `XYLayoutEditPolicy`) and override the `createChildEditPolicy` method to return a `SelectionHandlesEditPolicy` that you implement that creates the handles the way you want them to look.